# useNavigate not redirecting after a post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have been on this for quite some time now, and I can't seem to figure out why react useNavigate isn't working as expected.
It's not working as it is taking me to 'currentPage1' instead of redirecting to '/'

This is my router config:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/" exact element={<HomePage />} />
     <Route path="/form" element={<MultiPageForm />} />
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

MultiPageForm

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_API_URL } from '../utils/constants';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

function MultiPageForm() {
  // State variables to hold form data
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  // State variable to keep track of current page
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      // Send form data to backend using Axios
      await axios.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/api/form/submit-form`, { email, text });

      navigate('/')

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
    
    // Reset form data and current page
    setEmail('');
    setText('');
    setCurrentPage(1);
  
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {currentPage === 1 && (
        <>
          <h1>Fill in the Form</h1>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(2)}>Start Form</button>
        </>
      )}
      {currentPage === 2 && (
        <>
          <label>
            Email:
            <input
              type="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentPage(1)}>
            Previous
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentPage(3)}>
            Next
          </button>
        </>
      )}
      {currentPage === 3 && (
        <>
          <p>Your email: {email}</p>
          <label>
            Text:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={text}
              onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentPage(2)}>
            Previous
          </button>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}

export default MultiPageForm;
```

HomePage

```
const HomePage = () => {
      // ️ redirects to an external URL
      window.location.replace('https://www.google.com');
};

export default HomePage;
```

I'm using a similar code in several other parts of the application, including the login page, and they all work fine, except here. Someone pls help find what I'm missing.

Comment: can you add your package.json file in the question as well ?

Comment: Are you sure your `axios.post` is getting resolved ? may be you should check the console whether it is going into the catch block or not

Comment: Only reset the form data & page if the api call fails.

Comment: @yaakov yeah that's correct. Do you think the the navigation is failing as the component is re-rendering for the state update ?

Comment: @DanteDX I'm pretty sure that's what's happening.

Comment: `setPassword` appears to be undefined in your code, but once commented out the navigation appears to happen as I'd expect it to. I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Here is a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usenavigate-not-redirecting-after-a-post-request-ceblg3) demo of your code.

Comment: @DanteDX yes axios.post is getting resolved

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your component like the following?
See where I marked the changes!

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { BASE_API_URL } from "../utils/constants";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function MultiPageForm() {
    // State variables to hold form data
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    // State variable to keep track of current page
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // Function to handle form submission
    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            // Send form data to backend using Axios
            const responseFromPost = await axios.post(
                `${BASE_API_URL}/api/form/submit-form`,
                {
                    email,
                    password
                }
            );
            /* THE CHANGES ARE HERE!*/
            console.log("responseFromPost", responseFromPost);
            // Reset form data and current page
            setEmail("");
            setPassword("");
            setCurrentPage(1);

            // redirecting
            navigate("/");
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {currentPage === 1 && (
                <>
                    <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
                    <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(2)}>
                        Start Form
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
            {currentPage === 2 && (
                <>
                    <label>
                        Email:
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentPage(1)}>
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentPage(3)}>
                        Next
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
            {currentPage === 3 && (
                <>
                    <p>Your email: {email}</p>
                    <label>
                        Text:
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={text}
                            onChange={event => setText(event.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => setCurrentPage(2)}>
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </>
            )}
        </form>
    );
}

export default MultiPageForm;
```